# How to show parent table column name in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, relationship

How to show parent table column name in ruby on rails?

I want to show company_name which is situated company_id like as 1, post is child table name, where is foreign key company_id, I want to replace company_name where is situated company_id.

This is my work-

Controller:

```
@post = Post.paginate(page: params[:page], :per_page => 10).order('job_view_count DESC')
```

View:

```
<% @post.each do |p| %>
  <%= p.jpost_title %>
  <%= p.company_id %> # I want to show company_name on this place
  <%= p.post_location %>
<% end %>
```

User model:

```
 class User< ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :posts, :foreign_key => :company_id
   has_many :companies
 end

 class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
   belongs_to :company
 end
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<% @post.each do |p| %>
  <%= p.jpost_title %>
  <%= p.company.company_name %>
  <%= p.post_location %>
<% end %>
```

To keep it DRY & to stop the [law of demeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter) issue, you'll want to use [`.delegate`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Module.html#method-i-delegate) in your `Post` model:

```
#app/models/post.rb
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :company
   delegate :company_name, to: :company #-> @post.company_name
end
```

This will allow you to use:

```
<% @post.each do |p| %>
  <%= p.jpost_title %>
  <%= p.company_name %>
  <%= p.post_location %>
<% end %>
```

---

To give you context (so you understand the issue / solution), `company_id` is the [`foreign key`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key) inside the `posts` table.

The foreign key is a relational database feature - it allows the db to "reference" data in other tables through they key you provide:

[image]

In your case, `company_id` denotes the `id` of the `Company` record for your post. The issue you have is that when calling this directly, you're going to get an `integer` returned (the `company_id` id).

To pull the associative object (IE `@post.company`), you need to rely on [ActiveRecord](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html) to populate it... which is why you should call `@post.company` (IE `post belongs_to company`) to get access to such attributes as its `name` etc:

```
@post.company_id #-> 1
@post.company.company_name #-> "Test"
```

Using `delegate` pushes your specific requests through to the `company` object, allowing you to call the defined methods on the `@post` object directly.

Comment: I'm about to write the `delegate` :)

Comment: It's epic isn't it - saves us so much time and effort!!

Comment: Hope you're doing well buddy & wishing you a happy new year.

Comment: Wish You the same dude :)

Answer (score 1):

You can just do `<%= p.company.campany_name %>` to display the name of the company instead of `company_id`.

Answer (score 0):

In your `Post` model you have `belongs_to :company`, therefore you can access the `Company` through `post.company`.

In Pavan's answer you would get an error if a `Post` doesn't have a `Company`.

I think you should add validations in your `Post` model as:

```
validates :user_id, :company_id, presence: true
```

If you assume that a `Post` does not require a `Company` you can change your view to:

```
<% @posts.each do |p| %>
  <%= p.jpost_title %>
  <%= p.company %>
  <%= p.post_location %>
<% end %>
```

And add a `to_s` method in your `Company` model:

```
# Returns name if present, otherwise id    
def to_s
  name || id
end
```

(I would suggest using `@posts` instead of `@post` since it is a convention to use plural form for multiple objects.)